# Should Kotlin's suspend function be allowed for valid CDI Producers / Beans

Tags: spring, cdi, kotlin-coroutines, quarkus, micronaut

According to Jakarta's CDI 2.0 (and 4.0 as well) spec:
https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/2.0/cdi-spec-2.0.html#producer_method

> If a producer method return type contains a wildcard type parameter or
> is an array type whose component type contains a wildcard type
> parameter, the container automatically detects the problem and treats
> it as a definition error.

CDI spec is not precise enough. I'm not certain if it refers to a class definition or generated bytecode (for JVM languages). That may impact Kotlin's suspend functions.

Kotlin's compiler transforms suspend function into continuation passing style (CPS). It analyzes the context in which coroutine is going to be executed and do a transformation into a state machine with local variables representing a coroutine's state.
It adds Continuation and wildcard result (Any?) because Kotlin does not support union types.

Then depending on various factor the same Continuation object (related to function invocation) can be passed from one suspended function to another if they are bounded within the same state machine.

My understanding is that Continuation is instantiated when the suspend function is called for the first time at runtime. Whenever we call the same function from different contexts we create different Continuation instances.

I was exploring different frameworks and created several projects in Kotlin/Arrow and Spring, Quarkus, Micronaut where I define my hexagonal ports as type aliases:

```
typealias AssignKeyboard = suspend (String) -> Either<KeyboardError, Unit>
typealias AssignMouse = suspend (String) -> Either<MouseError, Unit>
```

Those are producers / beans definitions:

```
@ApplicationScoped // or @Bean // or @Singleton
// @Named(BeanName.ASSIGN_KEYBOARD)
fun assignLocalKeyboardBean(shellAdapter: ShellAdapter): AssignKeyboard = // code

@ApplicationScoped // or @Bean // or @Singleton
// @Named(BeanName.ASSIGN_MOUSE)
fun assignLocalMouseBean(shellAdapter: ShellAdapter): AssignMouse = // code
```

And an injection point:

```
class KeyboardController(
// @Inject
// @Named(BeanName.ASSIGN_KEYBOARD)
   private val assignKeyboard: AssignKeyboard,
) {
// code
}
```

Spring supports suspend functions for producers and I didn't have to specify a qualifier to inject it.
Quarkus was able to create producers from suspend function (recently they blocked it) and inject it with help of Qualifier.

This is an example how Quarkus represents:

```
kotlin.jvm.functions.Function2<String, ? super kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super arrow.core.Either<? extends rg.KeyboardError, ? extends kotlin.Unit>>, ?>
```

Micronout detects a wildcard without `@Named` qualifier.

The question how CDI should look like for suspend functions? Can we apply to them? Should smart analyzer be introduced? Continuation depends on an injection context, so maybe they should be skipped in analysis together with result.

More details can be found here:
https://kotlinlang.org/spec/asynchronous-programming-with-coroutines.html#asynchronous-programming-with-coroutines

**Update**

A full source code can be found here:

- https://github.com/gonciarz/cdi-quarkus
- https://github.com/gonciarz/cdi-spring
- https://github.com/gonciarz/cdi-micronaut

Comment: More information can be found at: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/29789

Comment: Yes, I know. I've opened it ;)

Comment: Right, I added the comment to help future readers follow the latest developments :)

Comment: Thanks @geoand, I provided all 3 repositories for quarkus, spring and micronaut.